# Insert date format in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php-5.3

I have a question for you I try but not received...I need to insert date into database:
My script:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker({
         format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
     });
 })
```

My html:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Date:</label>
     <input class="form-control marg-left-10" name="date" id="datepicker">
</div>
```

My php:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->input->post['date']));
```

data is inserted into database : 1962-12-31.
Please help me.

Comment: can you print this value $this->input->post['date']?

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
$this->input->post['date']
```

to

```
$this->input->post('date')
```

For more :- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [DateTime::createfromformat(string $format , string $time)](http://php.net//manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php). Ie:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $this->input->post('date'));
$stringDate = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```